# Data alignment in Excel or Matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab, csv, nan

I carried out an experiment and automatically got readings in a .csv file format.
However the apparatus was supposed to take a reading every 0.1 seconds, and sometimes it was offline.
However the apparatus kept counting but didn't print these in the csv file.
For example, it would go reading 98.5, 98.6, 99.0. 
I'm looking a way to put blank rows in where there is missing data, such as it'll read 98.5, 98.6, 98.7, 98.8, 98.9, 99.0. And to give values of Nan for these.
Doing it individually isn't an option, as there is a vast amount of data (864,00 for a day).
Any ideas on doing this in Excel or Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

## In MATLAB:

It looks like your data has one decimal digit. In order to avoid [floating point errors](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html#bqxyrhp), you can multiply the first column by 10 and [round it](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html), to create indices. (An alternative is to use [`ismemberf`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23294-ismemberf) from the fileexchange).

Now, create a matrix of `NAN`s of the desired size. After that, fill the elements corresponding to the indices you just found.

```
idx = round(A(:,1)*10);
x = NaN(max(idx)-min(idx),2);
x(idx+1,:) = A

A =  
         0    0.8147
    0.1000    0.9058
    0.5000    0.0975
    0.6000    0.2785
    0.7000    0.5469
    0.8000    0.9575
    1.1000    0.9649
    1.2000    0.1576
    1.3000    0.9706
    1.4000    0.9572

x =
         0    0.8147
    0.1000    0.9058
       NaN       NaN
       NaN       NaN
       NaN       NaN
    0.5000    0.0975
    0.6000    0.2785
    0.7000    0.5469
    0.8000    0.9575
       NaN       NaN
       NaN       NaN
    1.1000    0.9649
    1.2000    0.1576
    1.3000    0.9706
    1.4000    0.9572
```

## In Excel:

You can use `vlookup`. If it doesn't find the value, it will return `N/A`. The function used in the screenshot below is:

```
=VLOOKUP(D1;$A$1:$B$10;2;0)
```

[image]

Comment: I started to use Vlookup function, in excel. Would this help me? As in can I reference a value to a previous page, so if it looks up a value thats no there it should give a N/A

Comment: @MRaff16: Check the update! =) Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: (just pretend column E isn't there =P)

Comment: Hi, thanks got that working in Excel. Is there any equivalent way of doing this in Matlab?

Comment: Doesn't the MATLAB answer help you? `ismember` is somewhat similar to `vlookup`, but doesn't really fit here (although the slightly adapted `ismemberf` might). But, I think the answer that's already there should work just fine =) If you use `ismemberf`, you would still need to create a matrix with NaNs, so it will take just as many lines, and it will be a lot slower.